# Expose GET-Params for django-filter als CamelCase

Tags: django, django-filter, camelcasing

I was wondering if I can expose the GET-parameters required for [django-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/) somehow as `CamelCase` instead of `snake_case`.

Meaning changing
`http://example.com/api/v1/object/list?my_parameter=hello`
to
`http://example.com/api/v1/object/list?myParameter=hello`.

I know that I can transform the output of `djangorestframework` to `CamelCase` with this neat package: https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-camel-case/

I googled around for some time but couldn't come up with a clean solution.